# Error 500: We're sorry... due to javascript_include_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I've followed all the advice I could find on this issue, and yet when I run my app on the server I get a `Error 500: We're sorry...` error.

The `production.log` file tells me that this line is the offender:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

My `application.js` file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require fancybox
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
//= require_tree .
```

(And removing that last line didn't help.) Since it's asset-related, the relevant parts of my `production.rb` file are:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Any help will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this'll help anyone, but I needed these lines in my gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end
```